# Heiken Ashi Using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, technical-indicator

[image]
I was defining a function Heiken Ashi which is one of the popular chart type in Technical Analysis.
I was writing a function on it using Pandas but finding little difficulty.
This is how Heiken Ashi [HA] looks like-

```
                 Heikin-Ashi Candle Calculations
           HA_Close = (Open + High + Low + Close) / 4
           HA_Open = (previous HA_Open + previous HA_Close) / 2
           HA_Low = minimum of Low, HA_Open, and HA_Close
           HA_High = maximum of High, HA_Open, and HA_Close

               Heikin-Ashi Calculations on First Run
            HA_Close = (Open + High + Low + Close) / 4
                   HA_Open = (Open + Close) / 2
                           HA_Low = Low
                           HA_High = High
```

There is a lot of stuff available on various websites using for loop and pure python but i think Pandas can also do job well.
This is my progress-

```
   def HA(df):

       df['HA_Close']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+ df['Close'])/4

       ha_o=df['Open']+df['Close']  #Creating a Variable
       #(for 1st row)

       HA_O=df['HA_Open'].shift(1)+df['HA_Close'].shift(1) #Another variable
       #(for subsequent rows)

       df['HA_Open']=[ha_o/2 if df['HA_Open']='nan' else HA_O/2]     
       #(error Part Where am i going wrong?)

       df['HA_High']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','High']].max(axis=1)

       df['HA_Low']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','Low']].min(axis=1)

       return df
```

Can Anyone Help me with this please?`
It doesnt work....
I tried on this-

```
  import pandas_datareader.data as web 
  import HA
  import pandas as pd
  start='2016-1-1'
  end='2016-10-30'
  DAX=web.DataReader('^GDAXI','yahoo',start,end)
```

This is the New Code i wrote

```
    def HA(df):
            df['HA_Close']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+df['Close'])/4
...:        ha_o=df['Open']+df['Close']
...:        df['HA_Open']=0.0
...:        HA_O=df['HA_Open'].shift(1)+df['HA_Close'].shift(1)
...:        df['HA_Open']= np.where( df['HA_Open']==np.nan, ha_o/2, HA_O/2 )
...:        df['HA_High']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','High']].max(axis=1)
...:        df['HA_Low']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','Low']].min(axis=1)
...:        return df
```

But still the HA_Open result was not satisfactory

Comment: Does it work?  If not, what's the problem?  Please provide a sample dataframe also.

Comment: It doesnt work....
I tried on this-
      
 import pandas_datareader.data as web
import HA
import pandas as pd
start='2016-1-1'
end='2016-10-30'
DAX=web.DataReader('^GDAXI','yahoo',start,end)

Comment: Try this for you line that gives you an error:  `df['HA_Open']= np.where( df['HA_Open']==np.nan, ha_o/2, HA_O/2 )`,  but I think you also failed to define `df['HA_Open']`?

Comment: also do `import numpy as np` if you didn't already

Comment: Nope.No luck.
I initialized df['HA_Open'] =0.0 just before the line you suggested but still getting error-
KeyError: 'HA_Open'

Comment: Is it possible that we assign a specific formula for a particular cell (In this case first row of Column.df[HA_Open'] and write a function for subsequent rows for same Series.
Offcourse we trying to solve same thing but i just thought if some specific line of code exist!

Comment: The "New Code" you added above works fine for me.  I mean, I doubt it gives the right answer, but it doesn't crash or anything.

Comment: Ya It doesnt crash but df['HA_Open'] starts with NaN instead  returning ha_o/2

Comment: @Abbas Please don't inline images of code: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341357/3714940

Answer (score 22):

Here is the fastest, accurate and efficient implementation as per my tests:

```
def HA(df):
    df['HA_Close']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+df['Close'])/4

    idx = df.index.name
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if i == 0:
            df.set_value(i, 'HA_Open', ((df.get_value(i, 'Open') + df.get_value(i, 'Close')) / 2))
        else:
            df.set_value(i, 'HA_Open', ((df.get_value(i - 1, 'HA_Open') + df.get_value(i - 1, 'HA_Close')) / 2))

    if idx:
        df.set_index(idx, inplace=True)

    df['HA_High']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','High']].max(axis=1)
    df['HA_Low']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','Low']].min(axis=1)
    return df
```

Here is my test algorithm (essentially I used the algorithm provided in this post to benchmark the speed results):

```
import quandl
import time

df = quandl.get("NSE/NIFTY_50", start_date='1997-01-01')

def test_HA():
    print('HA Test')
    start = time.time()
    HA(df)
    end = time.time()
    print('Time taken by set and get value functions for HA {}'.format(end-start))

    start = time.time()
    df['HA_Close_t']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+df['Close'])/4

    from collections import namedtuple
    nt = namedtuple('nt', ['Open','Close'])
    previous_row = nt(df.ix[0,'Open'],df.ix[0,'Close'])
    i = 0
    for row in df.itertuples():
        ha_open = (previous_row.Open + previous_row.Close) / 2
        df.ix[i,'HA_Open_t'] = ha_open
        previous_row = nt(ha_open, row.Close)
        i += 1

    df['HA_High_t']=df[['HA_Open_t','HA_Close_t','High']].max(axis=1)
    df['HA_Low_t']=df[['HA_Open_t','HA_Close_t','Low']].min(axis=1)
    end = time.time()
    print('Time taken by ix (iloc, loc) functions for HA {}'.format(end-start))
```

Here is the output I got on my i7 processor (please note the results may vary depending on your processor speed but I assume that the results will be similar):

```
HA Test
Time taken by set and get value functions for HA 0.05005788803100586
Time taken by ix (iloc, loc) functions for HA 0.9360761642456055
```

My experience with Pandas shows that functions like `ix`, `loc`, `iloc` are slower in comparison to `set_value` and `get_value` functions. Moreover computing value for a column on itself using `shift` function gives erroneous results.

Comment: I have added the explanation to the post. For more insight you may refer to my _technical indicators_ project on [GitHub](https://github.com/arkochhar/Technical-Indicators)

Comment: the `.set_value` function doesn't seem to work on a Pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, set_value(), and get_value() are deprecated. Building off arkochhar's
answer, I was able to get a 75% speed increase by using the following list comprehension method with my own OHLC data (7000 rows of data). It is faster than using at and iat as well.

```
def HA( dataframe ):

    df = dataframe.copy()

    df['HA_Close']=(df.Open + df.High + df.Low + df.Close)/4

    df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    ha_open = [ (df.Open[0] + df.Close[0]) / 2 ]
    [ ha_open.append((ha_open[i] + df.HA_Close.values[i]) / 2) \
    for i in range(0, len(df)-1) ]
    df['HA_Open'] = ha_open

    df.set_index('index', inplace=True)

    df['HA_High']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','High']].max(axis=1)
    df['HA_Low']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','Low']].min(axis=1)

    return df
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that knowledgeable regarding Python, or Pandas, but after some research, this is what I could figure would be a good solution.

Please, feel free to add any comments. I very much appreciate.

I used namedtuples and [itertuples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) (seem to be the fastest, if looping through a DataFrame).

I hope it helps!

```
def HA(df):
    df['HA_Close']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+df['Close'])/4

    nt = namedtuple('nt', ['Open','Close'])
    previous_row = nt(df.ix[0,'Open'],df.ix[0,'Close'])
    i = 0
    for row in df.itertuples():
        ha_open = (previous_row.Open + previous_row.Close) / 2
        df.ix[i,'HA_Open'] = ha_open
        previous_row = nt(ha_open, row.Close)
        i += 1

    df['HA_High']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','High']].max(axis=1)
    df['HA_Low']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','Low']].min(axis=1)
    return df
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def heikenashi(df):
    df['HA_Close'] = (df['Open'] + df['High'] + df['Low'] + df['Close']) / 4
    df['HA_Open'] = (df['Open'].shift(1) + df['Open'].shift(1)) / 2
    df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc("HA_Open")] = (df.iloc[0]['Open'] + df.iloc[0]['Close'])/2
    df['HA_High'] = df[['High', 'Low', 'HA_Open', 'HA_Close']].max(axis=1)
    df['HA_Low'] = df[['High', 'Low', 'HA_Open', 'HA_Close']].min(axis=1)
    df = df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], axis=1)  # remove old columns
    df = df.rename(columns={"HA_Open": "Open", "HA_High": "High", "HA_Low": "Low", "HA_Close": "Close", "Volume": "Volume"})
    df = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]  # reorder columns
    return df
```

Comment: This code is not quite right as the HA open should be (HA_Open(-1) + HA_Close(-1))/2 and which requires iterating through the data frame as per arkochhar's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I adjusted the code to make it work with Python 3.7

```
def HA(df):
    df_HA = df
    df_HA['Close']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+df['Close'])/4

    #idx = df_HA.index.name
    #df_HA.reset_index(inplace=True)

    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if i == 0:
            df_HA['Open'][i]= ( (df['Open'][i] + df['Close'][i] )/ 2)
        else:
            df_HA['Open'][i] = ( (df['Open'][i-1] + df['Close'][i-1] )/ 2)


    #if idx:
        #df_HA.set_index(idx, inplace=True)

    df_HA['High']=df[['Open','Close','High']].max(axis=1)
    df_HA['Low']=df[['Open','Close','Low']].min(axis=1)
    return df_HA
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Perfectly working HekinAshi function.
I am not the original author of this code. I found this on Github (https://github.com/emreturan/heikin-ashi/blob/master/heikin_ashi.py)

```
def heikin_ashi(df):
        heikin_ashi_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.values, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])
    
    heikin_ashi_df['close'] = (df['open'] + df['high'] + df['low'] + df['close']) / 4
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if i == 0:
            heikin_ashi_df.iat[0, 0] = df['open'].iloc[0]
        else:
            heikin_ashi_df.iat[i, 0] = (heikin_ashi_df.iat[i-1, 0] + heikin_ashi_df.iat[i-1, 3]) / 2
        
    heikin_ashi_df['high'] = heikin_ashi_df.loc[:, ['open', 'close']].join(df['high']).max(axis=1)
    
    heikin_ashi_df['low'] = heikin_ashi_df.loc[:, ['open', 'close']].join(df['low']).min(axis=1)
    
    return heikin_ashi_df
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy version working with Numba

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def heiken_ashi_numpy(c_open, c_high, c_low, c_close):
    ha_close = (c_open + c_high + c_low + c_close) / 4
    ha_open = np.empty_like(ha_close)
    ha_open[0] = (c_open[0] + c_close[0]) / 2
    for i in range(1, len(c_close)):
        ha_open[i] = (c_open[i - 1] + c_close[i - 1]) / 2
    ha_high = np.maximum(np.maximum(ha_open, ha_close), c_high)
    ha_low = np.minimum(np.minimum(ha_open, ha_close), c_low)
    return ha_open, ha_high, ha_low, ha_close
```

Answer (score 1):

Will be faster with numpy.

```
 def HEIKIN(O, H, L, C, oldO, oldC):
     HA_Close = (O + H + L + C)/4
     HA_Open = (oldO + oldC)/2
     elements = numpy.array([H, L, HA_Open, HA_Close])
     HA_High = elements.max(0)
     HA_Low = elements.min(0)
     out = numpy.array([HA_Close, HA_Open, HA_High, HA_Low])  
     return out
```

Answer (score 1):

**No Loop Solution for DataFrames**

This was the simplest, easy to understand, no-loop solution I could come up with for **dataframes**.

- Temporarily store Heikin-Ashi output in 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c' columns
- 'h' based on yesterday's values so we can use `.shift(1)` and copy the first entry
- Replace 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close' with 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c'

**Python 3.9.7**

```
def heikin_ashi(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['c'] = (df['Open'] + df['High'] + df['Low'] + df['Close']) / 4
    df['o'] = ((df['Open'] + df['Close']) / 2).shift(1)
    df.iloc[0,-1] = df['o'].iloc[1]
    df['h'] = df[['High', 'o', 'c']].max(axis=1)
    df['l'] = df[['Low', 'o', 'c']].min(axis=1)
    df['Open'], df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'] = df['o'], df['h'], df['l'], df['c']
    return df.drop(['o', 'h', 'l', 'c'], axis=1)
```

Comment: I believe this is a wrong implementation. The next Open of Heikin-Ashi = (Previous Open Heikin-Ashi + Previous Close Heikin-Ashi) / 2. Instead, you are just using the previous NORMAL open and close.

Answer (score 0):

```
def HA(df):
    df_HA = df
    df_HA['Close']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+df['Close'])/4


    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if i == 0:
            df_HA['Open'][i]= ( (df['Open'][i] + df['Close'][i] )/ 2)
        else:
            df_HA['Open'][i] = ( (df['Open'][i-1] + df['Close'][i-1] )/ 2)


    df_HA['High']=df[['Open','Close','High']].max(axis=1)
    df_HA['Low']=df[['Open','Close','Low']].min(axis=1)
    return df_HA
```

This code works but calculates HA candles wrong.
Else statement is looking at normal candles for open and close instead of HA to calculate next HA Open.
Replace with:

```
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if i == 0:
        df_HA['Open'][i]= ( (df['Open'][i] + df['Close'][i] )/ 2)
    else:
        df_HA['Open'][i] = ( (df_HA['Open'][i-1] + df_HA['Close'][i-1] )/ 2)
```

Next is HA High and low. Calculations not right.

```
    df_HA['High']=df[['Open','Close','High']].max(axis=1)
    df_HA['Low']=df[['Open','Close','Low']].min(axis=1)
```

It is again comparing only against normal candles, instead of current normal candles High, and HA Open and HA Close. this code fixes the issue:

```
def HA_Initialise(df):
    df_HA = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])

    df_HA['Close']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+df['Close'])/4

    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if i == 0:
            df_HA['Open'][i]= ( (df['Open'][i] + df['Close'][i] )/ 2)
        else:
            test = []
            df_HA['Open'][i] = ( (df_HA['Open'][i-1] + df_HA['Close'][i-1] )/ 2)
            test.append(df['High'][i])
            test.append(df['Low'][i])
            test.append(df_HA['Open'][i])
            test.append(df_HA['Close'][i])

            high = max(test)
            low = min(test)
            df_HA['High'][i] = high
            df_HA['Low'][i] = low

    return df_HA
```

df is data frame with normal candle data, and df_HA is what we are building and looking into while code runs for needed calculations

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have everything in a list of lists; where each row has: time, open, close, high, low, volume.

```
        if candles:
            close_values = [sum(row[1:5]) / 4 for row in candles]

            previous_close = close_values[0]
            previous_open = (candles[0][1] + previous_close) / 2

            opens = collections.deque()
            opens.append(previous_open)
            for close_value in close_values[1:]:
                previous_open = (previous_open + previous_close) / 2
                opens.append(previous_open)
                previous_close = close_value

            candles = [[row[0], o, c, max(row[3], o, c), min(row[4], o, c), row[5]] 
for row, o, c in zip(candles, opens, close_values)]
```

This solution only uses list comprehensions and the collections module.

If you want to return the dataframe:

```
return pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            data=candles,
            columns=['Time', 'Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume'],
            index='Time',
            coerce_float=True,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas_ta as ta                      # TA-lib
import pandas as pd

Using Pandas implementation of ta was easiest and fastest at mine

```
dfHA = df.ta.ha()
```

I assume this wasn't available at the time the question was asked

Answer (score -2):

**Fastest solution I found.**

```
def HA(df):
    df['HA_Close']=(df['Open']+ df['High']+ df['Low']+df['Close'])/4

    idx = df.index.name
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    ha_close_values = self.data['HA_Close'].values

    length = len(df)
    ha_open = np.zeros(length, dtype=float)
    ha_open[0] = (df['Open'][0] + df['Close'][0]) / 2

    for i in range(0, length - 1):
        ha_open[i + 1] = (ha_open[i] + ha_close_values[i]) / 2

    df['HA_Open'] = ha_open

    df['HA_High']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','High']].max(axis=1)
    df['HA_Low']=df[['HA_Open','HA_Close','Low']].min(axis=1)
    return df
```

This solution is similar to ***user11186769*** with 2 additional optimization.

The major optimizations which gave a 3.5-4x speedup is this part:

```
ha_close_values = self.data['HA_Close'].values

length = len(df)
ha_open = np.zeros(length, dtype=float)
ha_open[0] = (df['Open'][0] + df['Close'][0]) / 2

for i in range(0, length - 1):
    ha_open[i + 1] = (ha_open[i] + ha_close_values[i]) / 2
```

**vs this:**

```
[ha_open.append((ha_open[i] + df.HA_Close.values[i]) / 2) for i in range(0, len(df)-1)]
```

The first difference is that in that answer there is an unnecessary and expensive call in every iteration. Which is this: `df.HA_Close.values[i]`. (It converts the series to a numpy array in every iteration.)

As you can see, in my solution I only calculated that value once and stored it like this: `ha_close_values = self.data['HA_Close'].values`, and used this value in the for loop.

The other optimization is using a numpy array with a fix size instead of a python list. Instead of appending to that list in every iteration, I just used the current index+1 to set the values of `ha_open`.

Comment: what is `self.` here?